# Toad for Oracle - Copy Column from Columns Tab without all details

Tags: toad

An arbitrary behavior in Toad that annoys me when composing my queries.
It is not a problem really, rather than an annoying issue.

If you describe any table in toad, or clicked on the table name from the Schema Browser, in Columns tab, copy and paste a column

Sometimes you get the column name only, and sometimes you get the column name with the details of the column {name length data type...etc}

When does toad coy the column name alone, and when does it copy the entire column description?

I searched many SO questions for something related, and google trying to understand how to copy only column name, but I didn'y find any reference at all related tho this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in Schema Browser,

- select any table and
- navigate to "Columns" tab (that's what you're doing anyway).
- Right-click, a menu should open.
- It contains the **Row select** item. If it is checked, when copy/pasting a *column*, you'll actually copy the whole row.
- Therefore, **uncheck it**.

Make sure you click on a column name when copy/pasting it; otherwise, you'll copy a column value you clicked on (such as Data Type or Null).

Comment: it worked, thank you, but, although that option was checked, why do I get the column name only sometimes, it doesn't make any sense, I think it is a bug

Comment: Huh, I don't know; my TOAD is 12.5. Which version do you use? I tried to simulate what you're saying (i.e. enabled "Row select" and tried to copy only column name) but didn't manage to. Could it be a bug? Certainly, but I don't know how to fix it, sorry ... perhaps you could contact Quest software.

Comment: The version I use is **11.6.1.6**, I can reproduce the issue by clicking on the cell than contains the column name (having row select option checked), and paste it on any text editor, redo these step multiple times, click, copy, past. I get about 50% 50% between full row paste and only column name only.  any way, it is fine with me now with the **Row Select** option unchecked.  Thank you

Comment: Right; I was patient enough and reproduced what you say 2 times out of 25. It seems that they improved that bug between those two versions :)

Comment: hmmm, because I get it exactly 50/50 I always thought it is a kind of a weird feature